# user updated data displays

Tags: java, android

I am trying to find an efficient way to display data based on user input. I have TextView/EditText to obtain the data I need. I want there to be 1 String (name) and 3 Double (rate, amount, time) for a financial calculator.

I want the user to be able to be able to put in anywhere from 1-10 different sets of the same data, but have my displays (TextView) be blank/invisible unless there is data to support them.

I would also like to avoid:

```
String debtName1, debtName2, debtName3, debtName4, debtName5, debtName6, debtName7, debtName8, debtName9, debtName10;
Double debtRate1, debtRate2, debtRate3, debtRate4, debtRate5, debtRate6, debtRate7, debtRate8, debtRate9, debtRate10;
Double debtBalance1, debtBalance2, debtBalance3, debtBalance4, debtBalance5, debtBalance6, debtBalance7, debtBalance8, debtBalance9, debtBalance10;
Double debtTerm1, debtTerm2, debtTerm3, debtTerm4, debtTerm5, debtTerm6, debtTerm7, debtTerm8, debtTerm9, debtTerm10;
```

as this seems really stupid. Also, I am planning on having the data be reorganized based on the "Term" so that it is easily displayed from smallest term to largest.

I was considering doing "pointers" but it didn't seem like the Java "work-around" method of pointers would really fit what I'm trying to do.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about arrays?

```
String[] debtNames = new String[10];
Double[] debtRate = new Double[10];
```

And then populate like this:

```
debtNames[0] = "someDebitName";
```

etc...

Comment: Assuming I do String[] debtNames = new String[10]  //10 being the limit....

Can I do

TextView newDebtName= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.debtName); and have it be

debtNames[1] = newDebtName

??

Comment: No, if you want an array of TextViews, you'll need to make an array of TextViews: TextView[] textViews;

Comment: How would I set up my layout with that?